# Why is Tomoko actions on her computer so exaggerated?

Tags: watamote

In episode 1 when Tomoko is looking up on "Gaagle Japan" on how to make herself look more cuter it seems her movements are quite exaggerated, to the point where she is using the mouse in a way no normal computer user would. (as the mouse wouldn't normally track while up in the air like that)

Why is she doing this? is this a parody from something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scene itself is a parody from Death Note when Light is writing in the Death Note.

[Comparative Video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_UTG05S5Ak)

The idea of the exaggerated movement of the mouse is that it's supposed to mimic what Light did with his pen as he was writing the name of criminals in the Death Note.

Also you'll notice all the shots of criminals dying in Death Note, in Watamote they are replaced with the sites Tomoko found, in a sense her "targets"

Comment: I remember seeing this in a [GIF from Thrills and Spills](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/7780?m=16331736#16331736).